# Core Data computed property always returns 0

Tags: core-data, swiftui, computed-properties

I am learning SwiftUI and creating a very simple app where some Ints are inputted on one screen (`Itemsheet`), a calculation is run in `app.xcdatamodel` and they are outputted on `ContentView`.

However, the computed value is driving me crazy. It always seems to show as 0. I'd love to hear if anyone has any ideas why?

Here is my code:

**ItemSheet.swift**

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

Stepper("\(days) days", value: $days)
Stepper("\(cost)€", value: $cost)
```

**app.xcdatamodel**

```
extension Pricing {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Pricing> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Pricing>(entityName: "Pricing")
    }

@NSManaged public var days: Int16
@NSManaged public var cost: Int16
public var costPerDay: String {
        get {
            if (self.cost > 0) {
                let newValue = String(format: "%.0f", "Cost per day: \(cost) / \(days)")
                return newValue
            }
            else {
                return "add cost"
            }
        }
        set {
            self.costPerDay = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

**ContentView.swift**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(entity: Clothing.entity(), sortDescriptors: [])
    var clothing: FetchedResults<Clothing>

var body: some View {
ForEach(clothing) { item in
Text("Days: \(item.days)")
Text("Cost: \(item.cost)")
Text("Cost per Days: \(item.costPerDay)")

}
}
}
```

Both the other Text views (`Text("Days: \(item.days)")`and `Text("Cost: \(item.cost)")`) are working fine, so guessing I am making a rookie error in the core data model somewhere?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your string to

```
String(format: "Cost per day: %.0f",  Double(cost / days))
```

`"%.0f"` is for `Float` or `Double` you are dealing with `Int16`

Comment: Hehe... of all the stupid and basic errors this has to win the award of the day! Thank you!